# How to write join query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to join two table

i can do it thorugh mysql query but do not know to how to do using codeigniter active records

```
SELECT mb . * , cls . * 
FROM membership AS mb
INNER JOIN classi AS cls ON mb.id = cls.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried looking here f.e.? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this query in `CI`

```
$query = $this->db->select("mb.* , cls.*", false)
->join("classi as cls", "mb.id = cls.id", "inner")
->limit(30, 0)
->get("membership");

var_dump($query->result());
```

Answer (score 0):

**It should look like this**

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('tbl1');
$this->db->join('tbl2', 'tbl1.id = tbl2.id');
$this->db->join('tbl3', 'tbl1.id = tbl3.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

*Follow codeigniter user guide for more details. [codeigniter/user-guide/database](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html)*